# file_puts_content permission denied on Windows 7 WAMP

Tags: php, permissions, wamp

I am trying to use file_put_contents on my local website to download some images from a website and save them to the C:\ drive. However when running the script I get an error

```
file_put_contents(C:\product_images\A): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I have full permission for the product_images folder and also the A folder inside.

I know I could just chmod in ubuntu but not sure what I could do with Windows. I just right clicked and selected properties and made sure all the users had all the permissions applied

```
    public function showImage() {

    $product_image = ['/ABCD/ABCD.jpg','/ABCDE/ABCDE.jpg'];

    foreach($product_image as $product_images) {
        $url = "http://images.url.com/product_images" . $product_images  ."";
        $letter = substr($product_images, 1, 1);
        $folder = 'C:\product_images\ ' .$letter . '';
        $new_folder = str_replace(' ', '', $folder);
        file_put_contents($new_folder, file_get_contents($url));
    }

    $success = "Success!";

    return $success;
}
```

Comment: `file_put_contents()` does not create folders. You need to create the folder prior to saving the file.

Comment: exactly. the folder must exist. If  you're trying to save a file try adding an extension, like .jpg

Comment: Yeah, the A folder does exist. But if I delete the folder it will just create a A file which I believe is the image just not in a file format because it has a file size.

Comment: So I am wanting the files to save like product_images\A\ABCD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents` works with URLs only if [**allow_url_fopen**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is on ("1"). Check it with

```
ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
```

Also notice that while your writing folder might have the required permissions, the *parent folder* may **NOT**. Both (possible) folders should have the permissions.

You can also test the folder if its writable (through [**is_writable**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php))

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($product_image as $product_images) {
        $url = "http://images.com/product_images" . $product_images  ."";

        $test = explode("/", $product_images);

        $folder = 'C:\product_images\ ' . $test[2] . '';

        $new_folder = str_replace(' ', '', $folder);

        $newer_folder = str_replace('/', '\\', $new_folder);

        file_put_contents($newer_folder, file_get_contents($url));

        echo '../product_images/' . $test[2] . '';
        echo '<br />';
    }
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out with explode()