# how can i give permissions to my logged in user to upload their pic to my upload folder?

Tags: php

I have a site where users need to log in before filling a form and their uploaded pic should be sent to the uploadfolder. i am working on wampserver on window.
When i want to move the file to the folder, but i am getting this error: `failed to open stream: Permission denied.`
**Here is my code:**

```
if (array_key_exists('terminervente', $_POST)) {
    // define constant for upload folder
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'D:/wamp/www/projet-fembuleuse/upload_test/');
$file = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['image']['name']);
if (empty($_POST['articlename'])) {
    $error[] = "Enter article name";
  }
     else{
        $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['articlename']));
     }

if (empty($error)) {
try {

  if ($pdo) {

   $sql = "INSERT INTO userarticles(id_user,name) VALUES(:id_user,:name);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":id_user", $id_user);
$stmt->bindValue(":name", $name);
if ($count > 0) {
   $success = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],UPLOAD_DIR.$now.$file );

  if (!$success) {
    $error[] = "File could not be moved";
  }
    else{
   header('Location: '.HOMEACCOUNT);
      exit();
 }

   }

}//end try
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error[] = "Eror in scrip".$e->getMessage();
  }
```

So how i should make my uploadfolder writable to move the users pictures there?
when i try to upload pic to the folder as the administrator..it works fine...but when i put a login form and i entered some login details of fictional users i have inserted in my db.. so that i can login and fill the form before uploading file and move to folder..it does not work...it is like only the administrateur can move file to the upload folder...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move\_uploaded\_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied " error after all configurations i did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after)

Comment: @Cristy: sorry for the duplicate.but i made research on internet before posting...the solution proposed did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your user doesn't have access to your server-side so they will never be able to directly write a file.

Permission is denied because the folder you are trying to write to does not have write permissions. Try to `CHMOD` that folder to `0777` and it should work.

If you are using a shared hosting here is how you can manually `CHMOD` a file: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-permissions-chmod-of-a-file

Comment: when i use the chmod,0777..i get an error...here - it is chmod(): No such file or directory - any idea??

Comment: Yes, windows doesn't have `chmod`. Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893823/file-puts-content-permission-denied-on-windows-7-wamp